# How can I check if the user's currently authenticated using Laravel Passport?

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel, debugging

In Postman - I'm logging in successfully with login endpoint and after that, I do a file upload which works successfully with the endpoint below.  The id and file path get stored successfully in the db.

I can conclude that in Postman after logging in and only attaching one piece of form data (which's the file being uploaded) - that the id and email display correct values in Postman. I can confirm it because if I run the `dd($id, $email);`, the correct values are returned.

However, on the browser - I'm trying to send up user id and email but I keep getting a 500 error in the logs that says: `"Trying to get property 'id' of non-object"`.

I'm guessing that in my FileUpload controller code (I'm using Laravel passport) that I need to do a check in order to see if the current user's authenticated, but how?  I've looked at all the docs, tried a ton of suggestions but to no avail.  I'm trying to send `Bearer` token in my post request but that's not doing it either.  What else can I possibly try?

Here's my frontend code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class Upload extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            selectedFile: null,
            id: null,
            email: ''
        };
        this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this);
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
        this.fileUpload = this.fileUpload.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("Inside componentDidMount()");
        let id = localStorage.getItem("id");
        let email = localStorage.getItem("email");
        console.log(id);
        console.log(email);
        this.getId(id);
        this.getEmail(email);
    }

    getId(id) {
        console.log("inside getId()");
        this.setState({id: id}, () => console.log(this.state.id));
    }

    getEmail(email) {
        console.log("inside getEmail");
        this.setState({email: email}, () => console.log(this.state.email));
    }

    onFormSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.fileUpload(this.state.selectedFile);
    }

    onChange(e) {
        this.setState({selectedFile: e.target.files[0]});
    }

    fileUpload(file) {
        const formData = new FormData();
        const accessToken = localStorage.getItem("access_token").slice(13, -8);

        console.log(accessToken);
        formData.append('file', file);

        const headers = {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + accessToken
        }

        axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/wall-of-fame', formData, {headers})
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response);
            }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form encType='multipart/form-data' id="login-form" className="form" onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
                <input type="file" name="file" id="file" onChange={this.onChange}/>
                <button type="submit">Upload</button>
            </form>
        );
    }

}

export default Upload;
```

Here's my backend fileUpload controller code (using Laravel Passport):

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class FileUploadController extends Controller {

    public function store(Request $request) {
        $filePath = $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName();
        $id = $request->user()->id;
        $email = $request->user()->email;

        // dd($id, $email);

        if (($user = Auth::user()) !== null) {
            $data = [
                'file_path' => $filePath,
                'user_id' => $id,
                'email' => $email
            ];

            DB::table('my.db')->insert($data);
            return response()->json($user);
        }
        return "failed";
    }
}
```

Here's login method in controller:

```
public function login(Request $request) {
    $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|string|email',
        'password' => 'required|string',
        'remember_me' => 'boolean'
    ]);
    $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);
    if(!Auth::attempt($credentials))
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Unauthorized'
        ], 401);
    $user = $request->user();
    $tokenResult = $user->createToken('Personal Access Token');
    $token = $tokenResult->token;
    if ($request->remember_me)
        $token->expires_at = Carbon::now()->addWeeks(1);
    $token->save();
    return response()->json([
        'access_token' => $tokenResult->accessToken,
        'token_type' => 'Bearer',
        'expires_at' => Carbon::parse(
            $tokenResult->token->expires_at
        )->toDateTimeString(),
        $user
    ]);
}
```

Here's my middleware:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'auth'
], function () {
    Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');
    Route::post('signup', 'AuthController@signup');
    Route::post('wall-of-fame', 'FileUploadController@store');

    Route::group([
        'middleware' => 'auth:api'
    ], function() {
        Route::get('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
        Route::get('user', 'AuthController@user');
        Route::get('wall-of-fame', 'FileUploadController@fileUpload');
    });
});
```

Comment: You dont seem to be sending the bearer token with axios request. And to prevent this non object error, it would be good to check if the user is authenticated first, in the controller if not the middleware.

Comment: Please send the bearer token with your axios request.
```axios.post('http://myendpoint/api/auth/dash', formData, {
    headers: {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
    }
  })
```

Comment: @user3532758 ahh yeah I posted the wrong snippet, my bad.  I've changed it.  I've also posted my middleware.  what's a good way to check if user's authenticated via middleware?

Comment: @LavShinde just posted the correct snippet, my apologies

Comment: You are already using the `auth:api` middleware, you would not have hit the controller if you were not authenticated. My only suggestion now is to switch $request->user() to `auth()->user()` or `auth()->guard('api')->user()`, but that is a long shot.

Comment: To check the auhenticated user with apiyou should use `$user = Auth::user('api')`